# save model and ajax in one action yii2

Tags: php, ajax, model, yii2

My problem, I don't know how to set `$model->code_reg` when I use Ajax post. I want save my model code_reg for looping for my ajax post. But its my controller create not work save it

This is my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->field($model, 'code_reg')->textInput(['readonly' => true]) ?> 
</div> <!--I'm using random code and It's was display for this--> 
<table id="sampleTbl", class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Age</th> 
    </thead><tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>William</td>
            <td>29</td>
        </tr><tr>
            <td>Nency</td>
            <td>25</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="form-group">
    <?= Html::submitButton('Create',['class' => 'btn btn-success', 'id' => 'idOfButton']) ?>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery function:

```
$('#idOfButton').click(function(){
    var TableData = new Array();
    $('#sampleTbl tr').each(function(row, tr){
        TableData[row]={
            'name' : $(tr).find('td:eq(0)').text(),
            'age' : $(tr).find('td:eq(1)').text()
        }
    }); 
    TableData.shift();  // first row will be empty - so remove
    var jsonEncode = JSON.stringify(TableData);
    // alert(jsonEncode);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: "pTableData=" + jsonEncode,
        success: function(msg){
            // alert(msg);
        },
    });
});
```

This is my controller `actionCreate()`:

```
$model = new Mutiplearray();

if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
    $tableData = stripcslashes($_POST['pTableData']);
    $tableData = json_decode($tableData, true);
    foreach ($tableData as $key) {
        $model->isNewRecord = true;
        $model->id = NULL;
        $model->name = $key['name'];
        $model->age = $key['age'];
        $model->code_reg = $model->code_reg; // <---This is my problem I can't save it `code_reg` for ajax looping 
        $model->save();
    }

    return $this->redirect(['index']);
} else {
    return $this->render('create', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

I got `not set` for `code_reg` when I use like this. How to save model when I use ajax too?

Comment: Hmm and where do You set data to `$model->code_reg` in `actionCreate`?

Comment: no. `$model->code_reg` Its from form `activeForm` it set from jQuery. I have database `name, age, code_reg` name and age send using ajax and code_reg send from form  `activeForm`

Comment: show your acrtiveForm please ..

Comment: Okey but in action you create empty model `$model = new Mutiplearray();` without any data.

Comment: Its already in there `<?= $form->field($model, 'code_reg')->textInput(['readonly' => true]) ?>` set using jQuery and the` table` its inside activeForm `<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>`

Comment: when use gii action create use like this so `$model = new Mutiplearray(); if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {return $this->redirect(['index']);}` @PatrykRadziszewski

Comment: what is the result of print_r($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()));die();

Comment: This is my result `Array
([pTableData] => [{"name":"Ristha","age":"30"}])` It's not send my activeForm. how to send it? when I using ajax post. Sorry for my late response, i hope you want too response again